# Next.js Vercel: route-loader.js 404 loading chunks

Tags: next.js, vercel

Our users are getting 404s from `route-loader.js` in a Next.js app deployed to Vercel. Anything that relies on `router.push` or the next `Link` component is prone to failure. It seems to be a caching issue, since everything works fine in incognito. I have pushed new builds with a logging message to quietly check if the new builds are being loaded in the users' browser: they are. It's just the chunks that seem to be cached and breaking.

Here is a screenshot from the console:
[image: screenshot showing the url and script]

I'm currently in the process of temporarily rewriting everything to avoid all the optimizations so we can have a functional app, but that's obviously not sustainable.